# NexusToArtifactory tool , unable to give artifactory url

Tags: nexus, artifactory

I am using nexus2artifactory tool to migrate from Nexus to Artifactory. In the initial setup menu, while giving the artifactory URL, Nexus2Art migrator tool is showing below error:
Unable to access artifactory URL. and errors in lines 435,548,473,407,556 of urllib2.py
HTTP Error 503 : Service unavailable
Artifactory URL is accessible in browser and running successfully. But the tool is not able to recognize artifactory. I have checked the log files artifactory.log, request.log, access.log and there is no errors in the log files. Please give me suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: What do you see in the artifactory.log, access.log and request.log files in Artifactory? 
Have you inserted the credentials correctly in the migration tool?

Comment: There are no errors in the log files. The url itself is throwing error without allowing me to proceed to next step i.e.,user name and password.

Comment: Hope the artifactory service is up and running.
I am able to connect to Artifactory URL. But I am not sure which folder to specify as Nexus_Path. I am getting an error as " Given path is not a valid Nexus instance. " Can you help me in that ?